# What is the reason JSON.parse() acts differently?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I can not determine the difference between these two approaches:

```
let gigi;
if(localStorage.getItem('gigi')){
    gigi = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gigi'))
}else{
    gigi=[]
}
console.log(gigi);
```

While the code above shows empty array, the below one shows up null. Why?

```
let aa=[]
let che =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('aa'))
console.log(che);
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing in local storage with the key "aa"?

Comment: There is neither of them. I just purposely want to create two different and new ones

Comment: The first version creates an empty array when the key doesn't exist, the second one doesn't.

Comment: What's the purpose of the unused `let aa=[]` variable in the 2nd version?

Comment: Note that `let aa` and `aa` in `localStorage.getItem('aa')` have absolutely nothing to do with each other. The `let aa=[]` doesn't have any effect on your code.

Comment: @Barmar, I am just taking class, and tested without if..else statements, and noticed that the console result of mine and tutor's are different.

Comment: @Ivar good point, so when we declare any code/variable, it doesn't affect to our storage API, did I get right?

Comment: Yes. `getItem()` retrieves something from the local storage, which is completely separate from any variables in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`getItem` will return the value `null` if no value exists at that key in storage.

In the first code, this branch:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('gigi')){
```

excludes that possibility. In the second code, you're not doing any such test, you're passing it into `JSON.parse` regardless. `JSON.parse(null)` will coerce the `null` into a string, and will then parse `'null'` into the value `null`.

If you want to do this concisely, you can do

```
const gigi = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('aa') ?? '[]')
```

Comment: Hi, Barmar again. 1st: ?? - is this ternary operator? 2nd: I'm testing, even I do not have such (gigi) variable declared, it should assign empty array to gigi, right? so, that is what I am doing in second code.

Comment: @UlviEnzo `??` is the nullish coalescing operator. `x ?? y` evaluates to `y` if `x` is null or undefined, or `x` otherwise. It's more precise than `||` since it excludes the empty string (which may be contained in storage), but is pretty new.

Comment: In this case, `||` may be what you actually want, since an empty string is invalid JSON. Unless you want this to trigger an error.

Comment: Got a note, did not know that. Thanks you both

Comment: @CertainPerformance - but what you mean by more precise? Could you show by sample please?

Comment: @UlviEnzo In contrast, `||` will alternate if the expression on the left is falsey, but not null nor undefined. I tend to use `??` whenever I know the expression on the left, if I want to exclude it and use the expression on the right, is definitely `null` or `undefined`. `'' ?? 5` results in `''`. `0 ?? 5` results in `0`. `0 || 5` results in `5`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance so ?? goes falsey only when result is null or undefined, right?

Comment: @UlviEnzo Yes, so if I want to implement "Exclude null and exclude undefined", I use `??`.